# Query returning different results for desktop client and phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

This is using `mysql 5.7.33`

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN checkin_date=@last_ci+INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN @n ELSE @n:=@n+1 END AS g,
    @last_ci := checkin_date As checkin_date,
    calendar_id
FROM (
        select 1 calendar_id, '2021-04-10' checkin_date union all
        select 1, '2021-04-20' union all
        select 1, '2021-04-21' union all
        select 1, '2021-04-22' union all
        select 1, '2021-04-25'
   ) x,
   (SELECT @n:=0) r
ORDER BY checkin_date
```

This is the correct result which is returned by HeidiSql (11.1.x)

[image]

and the same query performed by phpMyAdmin gives bogus `g` column (`php 7.x`)

[image]

What can I do to get the same output with phpMyadmin?

Comment: Try to init all variables. `(SELECT @n:=0, @last_ci:='1970-01-02') r`. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=5ba0ed69eaa026e5145f994416faa779

Comment: Tnx, it's not easy to catch since mysql doesn't give any hints, only odd output.

Comment: *mysql doesn't give any hints* What hint do you need? Non-initialized variable assumed to be a constant with NULL value (fixed in version 8+).

Comment: Either way it's not easy to catch..